# Assembler debug of undefined expression

Tags: c, assembly, undefined, x86-64

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how compilers produce code for **undefined** expressions e.g. for the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    i = i++;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the assembler code generated by gcc 4.8.2 (Optimisation is off -O0 and I’ve inserted my own line numbers for reference purposes):

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
(1) 0x0000000000000000 <+0>:    push   %rbp
(2) 0x0000000000000001 <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
(3) 0x0000000000000004 <+4>:    movl   $0x5,-0x4(%rbp)
(4) 0x000000000000000b <+11>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
(5) 0x000000000000000e <+14>:   lea    0x1(%rax),%edx
(6) 0x0000000000000011 <+17>:   mov    %edx,-0x4(%rbp)
(7) 0x0000000000000014 <+20>:   mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
(8) 0x0000000000000017 <+23>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
(9) 0x000000000000001c <+28>:   pop    %rbp
(10) 0x000000000000001d <+29>:  retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Execution of this code results in the value of `i` remaining at the value of **5** (verified with a `printf()` statement) i.e. `i` doesn't appear to ever be incremented. I understand that different compilers will evaluate/compile undefined expressions in differnet ways and this may just be the way that gcc does it i.e. I could get a different result with a different compiler.

With respect to the assembler code, as I understand:

Ignoring line - 1-2 setting up of stack/base pointers etc.
line 3/4 - is how the value of **5** is assigned to `i`.

Can anyone explain what is happening on line 5-6?  It looks as if `i` will be ultimately reassigned the value of **5** (line 7), but is the increment operation (required for the post increment operation `i++`) simply abandoned/skipped by the compiler in the case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These three lines contain your answer:

```
lea    0x1(%rax),%edx
mov    %edx,-0x4(%rbp)
mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
```

The increment operation isn't skipped. `lea` is the increment, taking the value from `%rax` and storing the incremented value in `%edx`. `%edx` is stored but then overwritten by the next line which uses the original value from `%eax`.

They key to understanding this code is to know how `lea` works. It stands for [*load effective address*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Useful_side_effect), so while it looks like a pointer dereference, it actually just does the math needed to get the final address of [whatever], and then keeps the address, instead of the value *at* that address. This means it can be used for any mathematical expression that can be expressed efficiently using addressing modes, as an alternative to mathematical opcodes. It's frequently used as a way to get a multiply and add into a single instruction for this reason. In particular, in this case it's used to increment the value and move the result to a different register in one instruction, where `inc` would instead overwrite it in-place.

Answer (score 5):

Line 5-6, is the `i++`. The `lea 0x1(%rax),%edx` is `i + 1` and `mov %edx,-0x4(%rbp)` writes that back to `i`. However line 7, the `mov %eax,-0x4(%rbp)` writes the original value back into `i`. The code looks like:

```
(4) eax = i
(5) edx = i + 1
(6) i = edx
(7) i = eax
```